# Reading data from session couse data reset(php)

Tags: php, variables, session, reset

I am having trouble with sending variable with session. Goal is to automaticaly add user id in tree menu item, after successfull login.
Login code:
in if clause when login is success

```
$data['login']=true;
    $row = $db->fetchAssoc($res);
    $data['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id_user'];
    $data['id_user']=$row['id_user'];
}
else {
    $data['login']=false;
}
$data['success']=true;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Function for adding tree node code bellow:

```
 $_POST['action'] == "addNode"){ 
$uid= $_SESSION['id']; 
$id = clean($_POST['id']);
$leaf = clean($_POST['leaf']);
if($leaf == "true"){
    ..insert clause
}
...insert clause(inserting in database)
}
```

When I try to add new item in tree node, the user id is read correctly once and doesn't work   until I dont refresh page(checked with firebug).

If someone can help me I will apreciate.

Comment: At a guess you aren't starting the session? You need to call session_start() before you can properly use $_SESSION to store data

Comment: I did put session_start() at the top of php file, also tryed without it and it's same effect.

Comment: I've managed my problem with Cookie, at login.php I have seted cookie with `setcookie(name,variable,false,"/",false,)` and in other file I simply set cookie in defined variable `$variable=$_COOKIE['nameofcookie'];`                                       I hope that will help someone.